# I have difficulty with a query in symfony

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, repository

I have Entity **tag [ id , title ]** and Entity **annonce [id, title]** .

Tag and annonce in relation **ManyToMany**,

So i have assiciation **annonce_tag [ annonce_id, tag_id ]**

I have only repository **tag** and repository **annonce**, i dont have annonce_tag repository

and i want to make query to get the TOP for example 3 tags most used

Who has suggestions to make this query

**/*---------Updated----------*/**

I have tried this one in Tag Repository but not working

```
   return $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t.id','count(a)')
        ->innerJoin('t.annonces', 'a')
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that :

```
SELECT tag.id, count(annonce.id) from App:Tag tag JOIN tag.annonces annonce GROUP BY tag.id ORDER BY count(annonce.id) desc
```

You will get an ordered list of tags with the number of linked annonce for each

Comment: I have transform your code to this     return $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->select('t.id','count(a)')
            ->innerJoin('t.annonces', 'a')
            ->getQuery()->getResult(); is true?

Comment: You're missing the group by and order by part :)

Comment: And also, you should use getScalarResult instead of getResult

Answer (score 0):

You can write a join DQL query as below, just change to values and semantics to fit your scenario:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->select('COUNT(a) AS HIDDEN annonceNumber', 't')
    ->innerJoin('t.annonce', 'a')
    ->groupBy('a')
    ->orderBy('annonceNumber', 'DESC')
    ->limit(3)
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Why you set annonce_id 5?, i want to see the must used tags in all the app

Comment: I was just showing you how to query the many to many relationship, that is why I said change the semantics and values to what you need.

I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do DQL like that

```
// in annouce repository
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->select('COUNT(t) AS HIDDEN usedTags', 'a')
    ->innerJoin('a.tag', 't')
    ->groupBy('t')
    ->orderBy('usedTags', 'DESC')
    ->limit(3)
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

hidden tells doctrine to use field in query but not return it as array in getResult()

Comment: its return annonces, but me i want return the tag the must used IN ALL annonces

Comment: 3 tags that are used in all announces?

Comment: yes i want to see the 3 tags must used in annonces look what i have tried ( i have updated the question )

Comment: in every or at least one?

Comment: not every not least one, for example annonce1 have tags car,bike and annonce 2 have tags car so the must used tags is car